# how to compress an unsorted list of numbers?

Tags: database, algorithm, compression, graph

I am working on compressing graphs. The graph is represented as an adjacency list i.e each node in graph maintains a list of adjacent nodes. The lists contain Node_IDs(4 byte integers) and they are ordered by popularity of each Node_ID(score). So, I end with up unsorted list of Node_ID numbers and I have to compress them while maintaining their present order, to store efficiently.

Comment: Compress for the purposes of serialisation, or compress with the purpose of being able to miminise space requirements in memory while you operate on the graph?

Comment: @Giam: sorry for not being clear. I want to compress each list separately to minimise space requirement in memory. I want to maintain order so that operations like finding Top-K neighbors given two graph nodes are fast.

Answer (score 2):

Something simple would be to do a basic [Huffman Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) on the Node_IDs or even sequences of Node_IDs and convert the most common one to take up a few bits and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get anytime the scores by knowing the ID-s then you can store them in any order.

Comment: No. The scores of ID's depend on the list, they are in. So, knowing just the ID can't get you the score.